# How can I install and use latest Git on Mac OS X 10.9?

Tags: xcode, git, installation, osx-mavericks, homebrew

I downloaded Git 2.4.3 from sourceforge via http://git-scm.com/download/mac for my Macbook Pro OS X 10.9.5, then installed it.

When I typed `git --version` into the terminal, this message appeared:

```
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. 
Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools
```

When I typed `which git` this appeared: `/usr/bin/git`.

When I typed `git version 2.4.3` this appeared: `git version 1.9.5 (Apple Git-50.3)`.

I then installed Xcode. When I typed the above commands into the terminal, the same results appeared.

I then uninstalled Git.

How can I install and use the most recent version of Git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install Git without using Xcode, you can use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (which is great for installing other tools as well) - it comes highly recommended. I prefer using Homebrew over the dedicated download and install options like you used for Git.

Once you have set up Homebrew, you can use it to install and update many other command line tools with a single command.

Installing Homebrew can be done like this:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Execute this in a Terminal, it will install Homebrew for your user. The [Homebrew Wiki](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#installation) has more installation options.

Once you have installed Homebrew, you can use it to install the latest version of Git:

```
brew install git
```

Just make sure that you update your `PATH` variable to include `/usr/local/bin`, since this is where Homebrew will install the Git executable. You seem to be facing the problem that your Terminal is still using a different Git executable on the path. To update your PATH variable, edit the file `~/.bash_profile` in a text editor and make sure that it includes something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

After saving this file, close your current Terminal window and open a new one - it should then use the new PATH setting.

After this, type

```
which git
```

to find the location of the Git executable that's used by your current Terminal session.

Comment: Homebrew required XCode command line tools.  If you do not want to register as a developer you need to install XCode then run the command I listed below.

Comment: Xcode current stable version requires OSX 10.10. Its beta version requires 10.11. 
Do I understand correctly that the suggestion here is to upgrade from OSX 10.9.5 to 10.10 so that I can install Xcode, so I can then install Homebrew, so that I can finally install Git? Is this the shortest route?

Comment: Mac OS X comes with a pre-installed version of Git, as you noticed. Xcode also has a certain version of Git. If you want to use the latest version of Git (which might be more recent than the one in Xcode), you have the option of installing a packaged version or going through something like Homebrew/Macports.

Comment: Also take a look here: http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/

Comment: Here are the steps I took to solve this problem, based on the accepted answer. 
I installed [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). 
Then I installed git via the Terminal by typing "brew install git". 
Then I typed "which git" which returned "/usr/bin/git". 
Then I typed "git --version" which returned "git version 1.9.5 (Apple Git-50.3". 
Then I pasted "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" into the Terminal. 
Then I typed "git --version" which returned "git version 2.5.0".
Then I typed "which git" which returned "/usr/local/bin/git".

Answer (score 3):

You may need the command line tools for XCode. After you install XCode, run `sudo xcode-select --install` to install them. Then try installing git again.