# How to continue using Git on mac after uninstalling Xcode (with Android Studio)?

Tags: xcode, git, android-studio, github-for-mac

I have installed Git on my Mac. When I do a "whereis" in my terminal the route is:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

I use Android Studio and the GitHub desktop client and had no problems so far.

Previously I had installed Xcode, but I uninstalled it a week ago. Since then, Android Studio does not detect Git, I get the following error:

> xcrun: error: active developer path
>   ("/Volumes/Vega/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not
>   exist, use `xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the
>   Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools (or see
>   `man xcode-select`)

Android Studio shows the same executable path to Git
indicating the terminal (`/usr/bin/git`), but when I click on the "test" button it displays the same error.

I do not handle very well Git from the terminal, always use the desktop client.

What do I have to do to continue using Git on my Android studio (or anywhere) now that I uninstalled Xcode?

I searched for information but I can not fix it.

Comment: See also here for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31632593/how-can-i-install-and-use-latest-git-on-mac-os-x-10-9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the Xcode command line tools at the very least.  If you're not a registered Apple Developer, however, I'm not sure how to get hold of them if Xcode is not installed.  If you are a registered Apple Developer, you can get them from the [Apple Developer Download site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).  It' probably best to re-install Xcode and you will get them as a system update.

That will give you a minimal development environment, and if you need additional tools/libraries you can build them via [Macports](http://macports.org) with the command line tools installed.

Comment: I prefer using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install additional tools. Once you have the Xcode command line tools, you can install the latest version of Git using `brew install git`.

Comment: @nwinkler Yeah there is the homebrew camp and the Macports camp; it doesn't really make alot of difference.

Answer (score 26):

If commands `sudo xcode-select --reset` and `xcode-select --install` does not work for you and you dont want to install xcode then just reinstall git manually via `brew`:

```
brew reinstall git
```

And open new terminal session

Worked for me

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. No need for 13GB of Xcode to install `git`.

Comment: `xcode-selet --install` and then `sudo Xcode-select --reset` was enough for me to fix git after uninstalling Xcode

Comment: Yes, please, set as accepted answer, by the way, in my case, Android Studio prompted a message saying something like that Xcode is missing and due to that, the git on Android Studio won't update the file, in order to fix that, I just went to the Android Studio Preferences > Version Control > Git > And set up manually the Git path on "Path to Git executable".

PS: In order to get the git path, you could just type "which git" in the terminal.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

Will reset your paths to the defaults if the command line tools are already installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
xcode-select --install
```